# Inherit Time Machine Backup Snow Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, time-machine

I have a Time Machine backup of a harddisk with Snow Leopard (HD1). The SATA cable for the disk failed and got replaced. The HD was replaced out of precaution as well. The new HD (HD2) got restored from the Time Machine backup, but now if Time Machine is started up again it starts a full backup of the disk, and does not do an incremental on top of the old backups.

So the content of HD2 is equal to HD1, but Time Machine thinks otherwise.

How do I force Time Machine to inherit the backups for the new HD?
Anything related to the Terminal command `tmutil` does not work as that is only for Lion. This command does not exist in Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, and I'm using Snow Leopard (hate Lion/Mt Lion).

I found a discussion and a script at

http://simon.heimlicher.com/articles/2011/02/18/time-machine-volume-uuid

But I have not tried it myself just yet.  I will though.